# Delphi 10 Seattle IDE assertion failure when debugging project

Tags: delphi

I'm working on a project using Delphi 10 Seattle with Update 1. It's a new installation on a Windows 10(64bit) box.

When I debug the program, I get this strange error dialog:

```
---------------------------
Error
---------------------------
Assertion failure: "nRead == sizeof(ADDRESS) && self == addr"
in ..\win32src\thread32.cpp at line 141

---------------------------
OK   Details >>   
---------------------------
```

Bellow are the details of the error, when I click in Details button.

```
[203860EC]{dbkdebugide230.bpl} Debug.TDebugKernel.msgBox (Line 5934, "Debug.pas" + 30) + $0
[26B87F8D]{bordbk230.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $E0B5
[299EA55C]{bordbk230N.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $2F6E4
[299BC6BF]{bordbk230N.dll} Unknown function at @isDbkLoggingOn$qv + $1847
```

After that the IDE begins to have strange behaviors and I have to restart it.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the IDE/debugger. [File a bug report](https://quality.embarcadero.com) with Embarcadero. And consider upgrading to Delphi 11 and see if the problem continues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The security software CyberArk APM was causing the problem, after adding bds.exe to exclusion list solved the issue.